# Is it possible in Keras to apply the data augmentation only to specified directories?

Tags: keras

The number of training images for some classes in my data set is too small. I use the data augmentation feature of Keras. However, some classes have more than enough data. How could I instruct Keras, to apply the augmentation for each class in a different way? E.g. on those classes with enough data only H/V-flip, on the classes with few images rotation, shift etc.?

Currently the relevant code looks like this:

```
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1. / 255,
        rotation_range=45,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.02,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.02,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=True,
        validation_split=0.2
    )

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        self.train_base
        ,target_size=(self.img_width, self.img_height)
        ,batch_size=self.batch_size
        ,class_mode='categorical'
        ,color_mode='grayscale'
        ,classes=self.classes
        #,save_to_dir = "c:/temp/train_in"
    )

    learnhist = self.model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=self.nb_train_samples // self.batch_size,
        epochs=self.epochs,
        callbacks=callbacks_list,
        initial_epoch=self.start_epoch
    )
```

The directory in the variable `self.train_base` contains the sub-directories for all classes.

Answer (score 2):

For Keras you probably could implement multiple ImageDataGenerators and there define different augmentation approaches - Full disclosure, I have never tried that.

As there is the [Augmentor](https://augmentor.readthedocs.io/en/master/userguide/mainfeatures.html) package which has a beautiful pipeline approach to data augmentation, which makes it straight forward to augment different directories in a specific way.
 That's the road I tend to take.

```
import Augmentor

# Define augmentation pipelines
p1 = Augmentor.Pipeline("/path/to/images1")
# Initialised with 100 images found in selected directory.
p2 = Augmentor.Pipeline("/path/to/images2")
# Initialised with 100 images found in selected directory.

# Define different augmentations depending on the pipeline
p1.rotate(probability=0.7, max_left_rotation=10, max_right_rotation=10)
p2.rotate(probability=0.1, max_left_rotation=0, max_right_rotation=90)

# Augment images
p1.sample(10000)
p2.sample(10000)
```

Comment: I appreciate an upvote for the augmentor hint, yet wouldnt want this answer to be accepted, since I would also be interested in a native Keras solution to this problem.